# "Decir mucho o muy poco de algo"

Tags: modismos, significado

La expresión "*Eso dice mucho de él*" o "*Eso dice muy poco de él*", son diferentes en forma, pero ¿se utilizan para el mismo significado? ¿Son expresiones sinónimas o tienen matices distintos? Si los tienen, ¿cuales son estos matices?

Answer (score 4):

No son sinonimas. Puede parecer que ambas expresan decepcion, desencanto o mala opinion  acerca de alguien, pero mientras que esto es casi siempre asi con la segunda forma, no siempre lo es con la primera.

> Mi amigo Juan fue el unico que se quedo conmigo a limpiar despues de la fiesta. Eso dice mucho de él.

"Eso dice mucho de él" puede usarse tambien como "Eso dice mucho a su favor" y no solo como "Eso nos da un moton de informacion acerca de lo ruin y miserable que es esa persona".

En definitiva: "Eso dice mucho de él" dice mucho, bueno o malo, sobre alguien. "Eso dice muy poco de él", dice muy poco que sea bueno, luego casi todo es malo.

Tambien se puede usar "Dice bastante de ..." para querer decir que un hecho dice los suficiente de algo o de alguien como para hacerte una idea (de su caracter, de si es bueno o malo, etc.)